# why passing params do not refresh and have to refresh the new page update

Tags: react-native, navigation, routeparams

> i am trying to pass params to next page by calling id from previous
> page. but when you enter the next page the data does not appear
> immediately and you have to refresh the page which takes quite a long
> time, and faithfully calling new data, what appears is the previous
> data, you have to refresh the page to bring up new data. what is the
> solution?
>
> first page code

```
...//
         onPress={() => {
              setId(item.ID);
              navigation.navigate('Rekap_Bencana', {
                params: id
                });
            }}
...//
    const [dataBencana, setDataBencana] = useState();
      const [id, setId] = useState();
      useEffect(() => {
        getData();
      }, []);
      const getData = () => {
        fetch('http://192.168.0.103/aplikasi/restapi.php?op=getDatabencana')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
            // console.log(json);
            setDataBencana(json);
            // console.log(dataBencana);
          });
      };
```

> params page code

```
  const Rekap_Bencana = () => {
  const route = useRoute();
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const {params} = route.params;

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    console.log(params);
    }, []);

  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const getData = () => {
    fetch('http://192.168.0.103/aplikasi/restapi.php?op=getBencanaDetail', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: params,
      }),
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(resp => {
        setData(resp);
        console.log(resp);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `navigation.navigate('Rekap_Bencana',{params: id});` with `navigation.navigate('Rekap_Bencana',{params:item.id}`

Comment: If you are expecting `id` to become `Item.ID` within the next line of code then you wont get your desired result